# Understanding proof of a Lemma in complex

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a domain and $f$ is holomorphic on $U$. If the zero set $f^{-1}(0)=\{z \in U : f(z)=0\} $ has an accumulation point in U, then $f=0$ everywhere on $U$.

> Proof: Let $E$ be the non-empty set of accumulation points of $f^{-1}(0)$ in $U$. Then $E$ is closed in $U$ and $E \subset f^{-1}(0)$ by continuity of $f$...

I understand most parts of the proof that I didn't write but I want to make sure my understanding of why that $E$ is a subset of the zero set due to the continuity of $f$ is correct.

Is it because of the following logic: Suppose we have $x_n$ a sequence in $f^{-1}(0)$ that converges to some point $x\in E$, then since continuity preserves sequential limit, we have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, since $f(x_n)=0$ for all n, we must have $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Yes. Since $f$ is analytic it is continuous, so if $x_n \to x$ and $x \in U$ then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. In this case, $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: It is not crucial that $E$ is closed. It suffices that $f^{-1}(0)$ has at least one accumulation point in $U.$